# Will you need one answer or two?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Sometimes bitter, sometimes sweet,
>
> Sometimes I am a thing to eat,
>
> Sometimes in drawer, sometimes in tree,
>
> Sometimes a thing to do to me,
>
> sometimes one but joined of two,
>
> Sometimes a separate two in lieu.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Pair/Pear (and possibly also the homophone pare)

Sometimes bitter,

> A [balsam-pear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momordica_charantia) is very bitter

sometimes sweet,

> A ripe pear is sweet

Sometimes I am a thing to eat,

> A pear is a fruit

Sometimes in drawer,

> In a sock drawer, socks are arranged in pairs

sometimes in tree,

> Pears grow on trees

Sometimes a thing to do to me,

> You can pair a pair but you can also pare a pear.

sometimes one but joined of two,

> A pair of jeans for example is one thing consisting of two legs.

Sometimes a separate two in lieu.

> In cards, for example, you can have a pair of kings, which are two but separate.

Will you need one answer or two?

> A pear or a pair?

Comment: Perfect answer with excellent explanations.  My biggest shiniest +1 is yours!

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> Milk Chocolate / Milk and Chocolate

Sometimes bitter...

> Chocolate can be bitter or sweet

Sometimes a thing to eat

> Chocolate is edible?!!!!! oh yeah... it is!!!!

Sometimes in drawer...

> I happen to have chocolate bars stashed in drawers all over my house, tree- cocoa beans grow on trees

A thing to do to me...

> It's a stretch, but cover... as in chocolate covered strawberries... or dip...

Sometimes one...

> Chocolate milk would be one item that uses both chocolate and milk ingredients

Sometimes a separate...

> Milk Chocolate or Milk and Chocolate

Comment: Sorry.  It's nothing to do with milk and/or chocolate.  although the two together could make quite the example of the answer.  "Sometimes a thing to do to me" literally means that the answer can be done to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is:

> Chestnuts

Comment: The answer isn't Chestnuts.  I sort of get where you're coming from maybe, but I'd like to see your explanations all the same.

Comment: whats the point of a spoiler if you put the answer in a comment? @BrentHackers

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Is it still a problem if it isn't the answer and has no other info?  Serious question because I'd never thought about it.  Obviously in this case I could have just said "This isn't the answer" but are there any guidelines on how to comment on the contents of answers in this way without giving anything away?

Comment: @BrentHackers; personally i dont mind, it just makes the spoiler thing seem redundant